# How can I generate all groupings of a list in Python (preferably itertools)

Tags: python-3.x

Given I have a sequence eg  1 2 3 4 how can I generate the following groups from it using itertools:

(1) (2) (3) (4)

(1 2) (3) (4)

(1) (2 3) (4)

(1) (2) (3 4)

(1 2) (3 4)

(1 2 3) (4)

(1) (2 3 4)

(1 2 3 4)

The order doesn't matter...The way I grouped them is using separators : initially   I used three separators to divide them in four groups , then i used two separators to divide in three groups(2 ways of dividing in three groups) and so on

If it is not possible by itertools, how else may I generate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With *n* items in the list, there are *n-1* places between the list items where there may or may not be a separation. So we can let each grouping correspond to an *n-1*-bit list where `0` signifies a separation and `1` signifies no separation.

```
def generate_groupings(xs):
    for bits in range(2 ** (len(xs)-1)):  # int representing n-1 bits
        grouping = [(xs[0],)]             # grouping starts with first item
        for x in xs[1:]:                  # for each remaining item...
            bits, b = divmod(bits, 2)     # pop one bit off of the list
            if b:                         # case 1: no separation
                grouping = grouping[:-1] + [grouping[-1] + (x,)]
            else:                         # case 0: separation
                grouping += [(x,)]
        yield grouping        

list(generate_groupings([1,2,3]))
# [[(1,), (2,), (3,)], [(1, 2), (3,)], [(1,), (2, 3)], [(1, 2, 3)]]
```

In answer to your followup question

> What can I do to get a value from the above list of the form : `(1+2+3)*1 + (1+2)*2 + (3)*1 + (1)*1 + (2+3)*2 +(1+2+3)*3` i.e. the sum of elements in a group `*` length of the group

```
sum(sum(g)*len(g) for gs in generate_groupings([1,2,3]) for g in gs)
# 44
```

Comment: What can I do to get a value from the above list of the form : (1+2+3)*1 + (1+2)*2 + (3)*1 + (1)*1 + (2+3)*2 +(1+2+3)*3 i.e. the sum of elements in a group* length of the group [Sorry if it is an easy question]

Comment: @rjmessibarca Added it to the answer.

Comment: Is this the most efficient way in python to do so according to you?

Comment: No, I would never claim anything to be "the most efficient" without extensive testing, that would be ludicrous.